# change background-color of tags inside tag cloud based on the number of times it is used

Tags: tags, wordpress

Is there  a way I can set a different `background-color` for tags in the `tag cloud` in wordpress based on the number of times a tag is used.

Example: A tag that is used more will be shown in a darker color

A tag which is used less will be shown in a lighter color

I know the `font-size` can be altered as

```
add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args','set_cloud_tag_size');
    function set_cloud_tag_size($args) {
      $args = array('smallest'    => 14, 'largest'    => 20);
      return $args;
    }
```

How do I achieve similar behavior for `background-color` of a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wp_tag_cloud()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud) is a builtin wordpress method for the `TAG CLOUD` widget that accepts an array of font-sizes. you will need to write a custom method in your theme that takes care of changing the `background-color` instead of `font-size`.

Writing this method should be pretty straight forward and similar to the above mentioned method. you may find the code in `wp-includes/widgets.php` most probably.